# Eclipse Papyrus asociation but settings for multiplicity missing

Tags: eclipse, class-diagram, papyrus, multiplicity

i make a fresh settup of eclipse and papyrus. Had it run and used on a older machine a time ago.
I try to model a class diagram.
Crated a new Project with an class diagramm drop some classes.
I am able to make an "association" between my two classes. But on properties window the fields for multiplicity are not shown. (Like in all the turtorials on the web working out of the box)

What i could get propably wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figered it out random.
If you click on the Association Icon in the Edge Panel of the palette it works.
If you make a association by using the poles comming out of the classes it wouldn't work.